# How to use Jupyter Notebook inside docker for a whole project

Tags: docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run jupyter Notebook inside of a docker.

My docker-compose is made of multiple in-house services and modules - in python - that need to be accessed in order to run different experimentations.

Should I just add a new service docker that is using the same network as the other services?
Will it be enough to use modules that are specified in the other services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing you want to access Jupyter from a Docker based image,
if so, you can use the base image from

https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/minimal-notebook/tags?page=1&name=3.8

with port forwarding to your localhost

For example:

```bash
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/minimal-notebook:python-3.8.8
```

or run it with docker-compose

```yaml
#docker-compose.yaml

version: '3.8'
services:
  fjupyter:
    image: jupyter/minimal-notebook:python-3.8.8 
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

Using this base image, you can add all desired packages from `bash` but that wouldn't be the best approach since containerization dedicates each container for a specific service,
so it's better to use a dedicated image (hence a container) for each service.

Comment: It is indeed what I was looking for.
I am also interested in knowing how my different services installer in the docker-compose will be able to leverage the component that are installed in it, such as different classes,...



```yaml
#docker-compose.yaml
services:
  fjupyter:
    image: jupyter/minimal-notebook:python-3.8.8 
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
  service2:
    image: xxx
```

Comment: @Charley, you can build as many containers as you wish based on the same image, 
please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/multi-container-applications-docker-compose